# Do I capitalize "sincerely" in a correspondence signature?

Tags: capitalization, email, valediction, correspondence

I've been unable to find a consensus on whether or not one should capitalize the salutation before your signature in correspondence, email or otherwise.

For example:

> Sincerely,
>   XedMada

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to the Cambridge GCE , GCSE and iGCSE English Language Letter Writing Formats, it is recommended to write *Yours Sincerely* instead of just *Sincerely*. You should capitalize *Yours* in the Signature Block. . Here is an example:

> **Yours sincerely**
>   Lee Poh Lin
>   Lee Poh Lin (Ms)
>   P.R. Manager

The International Business Letter Format recommends capitalizing *Sincerely*:

---

[image: "Sincerely" is Capitalized.]

Overall most letter formats recommend capitalizing "Sincerely". Also, if you are writing the letter on paper, it is advised to write the Salutation Block in a *black* or *blue* pen.

Comment: If you handwrite the entire letter on paper, the salutation block should be written in the same color pen as the rest of the letter. For a more formal letter, this should be black or blue. For an informal letter, any color is fine.

Comment: Much of this answer is irrelevant. The question does not ask for alternatives to "Sincerely" or recommendations for ink color.

Comment: _Overall most letter formats recommend capitalizing "Sincerely"_ ~The Answer.

Comment: Surely it would be "Yours sincerely" not  "Your Sincerely". Capital S if you are doing just Sincerely because that is the start of the sentence, but there is no reason for capital S when Sincerely is the second word in the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

You should capitalize **only** the first word in salutation, as in

> Dear Mr. X
>
> My dear Mr. X

and also, **only** the first word of closing

> Sincerely
>
> Very truly yours

Comment: What is your authority for saying so? It seems to me that this is a matter of personal choice.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I did not post that answer as an authority or some subject matter expert. This is what I have seen being used most of the times, and before posting the answer, I Googled for any such generally accepted standards, (if any).

Comment: My experience is that there is no established practice. I myself am just as likely to write 'Yours Sincerely' as 'Yours sincerely'. With the increasing use of email with its greater informality, it's a question that is likely to of diminishing importance anyway.

Comment: Yours Sincerely is definitely wrong and Yours sincerely is right. English rules for capitalisation still apply to the closing and there is no reason for a capital S.

Answer (score 3):

The salutation and closing of a business letter are formulaic sentences, nothing more. That is, there is very little variation in salutations and closings from one business letter to another. But the rules for sentence construction, capitalization, and punctuation still apply. You will normally see the salutation and closing capitalized because they are normally the start of a new sentence.